# asmx web service authorization

Tags: c#, authorization, asmx

I have asmx web service(c#). I'm using Windows Authentication to access web service.
Now i need to provide some of web service methods only for speciefic user, for example Test. I cant find examples of such Authorization. Some examples of code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that web service have such restriction per memeber. Probably you will need to check the user rights inside of the web service members

```
   [WebMethod]
   public void HelloWorld()
   {
      if (this.DoesUserHaveRights(HttpContext.Current.User))
      {
          // do the work here
      }
      else
         throw new AuthenticationException();
   }
```

or somethign like this

Comment: if user is authenticated probably in the current HttpContext you can find it `HttpContext.Current.User`...